# how to configure wildfly server.log to have a fixed size and rotate daily and keep only logs for 5 days.?

Tags: logging, web-applications, wildfly, application-server, wildfly-13

snippet from standalone.xml,

**below configuration is not yielding the result.

```
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log" path="server.log"/>
<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<rotate-size value="500m"/>
<append value="true"/>
<max-backup-index value="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `periodic-size-rotating-file-handler` does not purge backups when the `suffix` attribute is used. See the [Wildscribe documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/wildscribe/subsystem/logging/periodic-size-rotating-file-handler/index.html). This has been requested, but there is not really a good way to determine which files would need to be purged.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the rotating file handler right from within your `standalone.xml`, like below:

```
<profile>
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">    
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
      <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
      </formatter>
      <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
      <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
  </subsystem>
</profile>
```